# Jboss: How do I add Maven Dependencies required for JBoss AS 7 in a Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, jboss, pom.xml

I am trying to deploy my Spring Boot war file in JBoss AS (7.1.0. Final). 
In the readme.txt inside JBoss, its mentioned as follows:

```
"Maven users should not use this jar, but should use the following BOM dependencies instead

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

This is because using maven with a shaded jar has a very high chance of causing class version conflicts, which is why we do not publish this jar to the maven repository."
```

I have tried giving the URL for all these dependencies, but not able to resolve them successfully.

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<!-- JBOSS AS 7 Maven Dependencies -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-enterprise-techpreview-group</id>
        <name>JBoss Enterprise Technology Preview  Maven Repository Group</name>
        <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
        <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<groupId>com.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringBoot</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>SpringBootDemo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JBOSS AS 7 Maven Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>jboss-as-7.1.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

While building the Spring Boot App using Maven, I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project SpringBoot: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   com.demo:SpringBoot:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies
>   for
>   [org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.3.8.RELEASE
>   (compile),
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.3.8.RELEASE
>   (compile),
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.3.8.RELEASE
>   (test), com.teamcenter.HelloTeamcenter:HelloTeamcenter:jar:1.0
>   (compile),
>   org.jboss.as:jboss-as-jms-client-bom:pom:jboss-as-7.1.0.Final
>   (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   org.jboss.as:jboss-as-jms-client-bom:pom:jboss-as-7.1.0.Final: Could
>   not transfer artifact
>   org.jboss.as:jboss-as-jms-client-bom:pom:jboss-as-7.1.0.Final from/to
>   jboss-enterprise-techpreview-group
>   (http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/): Access denied
>   to
>   http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/org/jboss/as/jboss-as-jms-client-bom/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/jboss-as-jms-client-bom-jboss-as-7.1.0.Final.pom.
>   Error code 403, Proxy Unacknowledged -> [Help 1]

Please let me know what I am missing?

Thanks in Advance

*UPDATE*

I have given maven URL also, but no luck:

```
     <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Repository Group</name>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

Comment: Why are you using Redhat's maven repository. Can you not use maven's central repository to download the artifacts ?

Comment: @RITZXAVI : Given maven URL also, but did not resolve

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your proxy is blocking your connection due a lack of/wrong credentials. Check your settins.xml file to configure it properly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Error code 403, Proxy Unacknowledged -> [Help 1] This message indicates a proxy issue. Could you post the proxy config (without password, of course) in your settings.xml?. Are you using a NTLM proxy? This kind of proxy is not supported by Maven.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I was able to fix my issue. Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my issue!

I added everything except the **version**:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

I added the  and it works!